# Loop a function which contain a list

Tags: python, list, function, loops

I would to run a loop which retrieve data from a function (not coded in the loop) for each base_currency. The code run without error but it displays 5 times (number of base_currency) the first items in the list instead of looping one after the other (the x in the function is not working properly).

The code:

```
base_currency = ['BTC','ABX','ADH','ALX','1WO'] 
length = len(base_currency)


d_volu = [] 
i = 0
while i < length:
    for x in base_currency:
        volu = daily_volume_historical(x, 'JPY', exchange='CCCAGG').set_index('timestamp').volume
    d_volu.append(volu)
    i += 1
d_volu = pd.concat(d_volu, axis=1)
print(d_volu)
```

Thank you

Comment: You're looping over `base_currency` twice (once in `while` and once in `for`) - remove the outer loop and put the `append` inside the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looping over base_currency twice as mentioned by @Grismar. You can avoid confusion by using list comprehension like this.

```
base_currency = ['BTC','ABX','ADH','ALX','1WO'] 
d_volu = [daily_volume_historical(x, 'JPY', exchange='CCCAGG').set_index('timestamp').volume
            for x in base_currency]
```

Comment: Thank you @Rahul. your code is simpler and works but i still have the same values. Could be something else

Comment: The code is simple and explains everything. The only black box here is a `daily_volume_historical` function call. Try manually calling that function with single value. Try `daily_volume_historical('BTC', 'JPY', exchange='CCCAGG').set_index('timestamp').volume` and see what it returns.

Comment: thank you. I solved the problem by looking into the function. Anyway I also learnt how to write loop more efficiently.